# How to parse JSON array in JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi I am trying to parse a JSON array of Objeckts into a JS array but it doesnt work.Does someone know what I have done wrong?

```js
 listOfBirds = document.querySelector("bird-list");
 var obj = JSON.parse(listOfBirds);
      console.log(obj);
```

```html
 <script type="text/template" id="bird-list">
        [{ "id":1, "name":"Haussperling", "latinName":"Passer domesticus", "imagePath":"resources/images/haussperling.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/haussperling.ogg" },{ "id":2, "name":"Kohlmeise", "latinName":"Parus major", "imagePath":"resources/images/kohlmeise.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/kohlmeise.ogg" },{ "id":3, "name":"Star", "latinName":"Sturnus vulgaris", "imagePath":"resources/images/star.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/star.ogg" },{ "id":4, "name":"Amsel", "latinName":"Turdus merula", "imagePath":"resources/images/amsel.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/amsel.ogg" }]
    </script>
```

Comment: try to debug the code. `listOfBirds` is null i guess.

Comment: To get an element by it's ID you need to use the #-sign with `querySelector`

Comment: yea its null. Normally should work without #

Comment: Luca Danke dir! Das # war das Problem. Hätte nicht gedacht :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) with the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property.

```js
var listOfBirds = document.getElementById("bird-list").innerHTML,
    obj = JSON.parse(listOfBirds);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<ul class="bird-list">
    <script type="text/template" id="bird-list">
        [{ "id":1, "name":"Haussperling", "latinName":"Passer domesticus", "imagePath":"resources/images/haussperling.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/haussperling.ogg" },{ "id":2, "name":"Kohlmeise", "latinName":"Parus major", "imagePath":"resources/images/kohlmeise.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/kohlmeise.ogg" },{ "id":3, "name":"Star", "latinName":"Sturnus vulgaris", "imagePath":"resources/images/star.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/star.ogg" },{ "id":4, "name":"Amsel", "latinName":"Turdus merula", "imagePath":"resources/images/amsel.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/amsel.ogg" },{ "id":5,"name":"Blaumeise", "latinName":"Cyanistes caerruleus", "imagePath":"resources/images/blaumeise.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/blaumeise.ogg" },{ "id":6, "name":"Elster", "latinName":"Pica pica", "imagePath":"resources/images/elster.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/elster.ogg" },{ "id":7, "name":"Grünfink", "latinName":"Chloris chloris", "imagePath":"resources/images/gruenfink.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/gruenfink.ogg" },{ "id":8, "name":"Mehlschwalbe", "latinName":"Delichon urbicum", "imagePath":"resources/images/mehlschwalbe.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/mehlschwalbe.ogg" },{ "id":9, "name":"Mauersegler", "latinName":"Apus apus", "imagePath":"resources/images/mauersegler.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/mauersegler.ogg" },{ "id":10, "name":"Buchfink", "latinName":"Fringilla coelebs", "imagePath":"resources/images/buchfink.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/buchfink.ogg" },{ "id":11, "name":"Ringeltaube", "latinName":"Columba palumbus", "imagePath":"resources/images/ringeltaube.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/ringeltaube.ogg" },{ "id":12, "name":"Feldsperling", "latinName":"Passer montanus", "imagePath":"resources/images/feldsperling.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/feldsperling.ogg" },{ "id":13, "name":"Türkentaube", "latinName":"Streptopelia decaocto", "imagePath":"resources/images/tuerkentaube.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/tuerkentaube.ogg" },{ "id":14, "name":"Rauchschwalbe", "latinName":"Hirundo rustica", "imagePath":"resources/images/rauchschwalbe.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/rauchschwalbe.ogg" },{ "id":15, "name":"Rotkehlchen", "latinName":"Erithacus rubecula", "imagePath":"resources/images/rotkehlchen.png", "audioPath":"resources/data/audio/rotkehlchen.ogg"}]
    </script>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have tried like that but it comes like :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: @ArTan, which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using the brackets und the Live ( its the chrome, Nodejs (I think so))

Comment: It does not. There is on Html a : 
<ul class="bird-list"> </ul>
befor the script. Could it be that a Problem? Even that is a class and not an id.

Comment: it should work with a class with the same name. but if you have the same id, then the `id` is not unique, which should be.

Comment: yea I understand what u mean but this is a part of a "Project" and the Html is there and we should not change anything but it seams that the Problem is somewhere else. Danke dir Nina!